# HPD region from empirical sample? How to display lb and ub?

Tags: r

Below is an R function generated to compute the 95% HPD interval from a unknown unimodal posterior distribution with pdf f. (HDP95). Once running this code, how do I actually generate the empirical estimate of the lower and upper bounds (i.e., something similar to proc print in sas?!)? Thank you!!

```
HPD95<-function(LargeSample){  
order<-sort(LargeSample)  
size<-length(LargeSample)  
  isize<-round(0.95*size)  
  lb<-vector("list", (size-isize))  
  ub<-vector("list", (size-isize))  
  inte<-vector("list", (size-isize))  
  for (i in 1:(size-isize)){  
    lb[[i]]<-order[i]  
    ub<-order[i+isize]  
    inte[[i]]<- ub[[i]]-lb[[i]]  
  }  
  minvalue<-min(unlist(inte))  
  position<-which(inte==minvalue)  
  interval<-c(lb[[position]],ub[[position]])  
  return(interval)  
}
```

Comment: You are referring to an "order" vector. Are you possibly confusing it with the `order` function? Also, why would an ub or lb be a multi-element vector? Seems like they should have only single elements. You should add comments to your code to indicate your intent since you appear to be very confused about R syntax.

Comment: I am still new to R. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be lazy:

```
library("coda")
hfun <- function(x,...) coda::HPDinterval(as.mcmc(matrix(x)),...)
```

(the extra machinery is needed because `HPDinterval` expects an `mcmc` object; this function applies it to a numeric vector).

Example:

```
set.seed(101); hfun(rgamma(1000,shape=2,scale=1))
##           lower    upper
## var1 0.02420174 4.977631
## attr(,"Probability")
## [1] 0.95
```